# JQUERY CSS Background

Tags: jquery

I currently have a DIV with a background image set as follows:

```
background: url(../images/site/common/body-bannar-bkground.png) repeat 0 0;
```

How can I remove this image and set a background-color only:

```
background-color: #C1A3A5
```

I know I can use JQUERY To set the new color like this

```
$('div#id').css('backgroundColor', '#C1A3A5');
```

but when I do this the background image is still in place. How can I knockout the background image? I also need to do this in reverse so how can I knock out the background-color?

Finally - would I be better to addClass() removeClass with the attributes set there or is basically the same factor?

thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the `background` shorthand rule to overwrite it:

```
$('div#id').css('background', '#C1A3A5');
```

Answer (score 3):

Messing with CSS directly in JS is never a good idea.

Better to use different classes for different purposes, with different CSS rules, and apply/remove them accordingly. You want to keep JS, CSS and HTML separated from each other as much as possible.

Your CSS:

```
#id {
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-repeat:repeat;
  background-color: #C1A3A5;
}

.backgroundImage {
  background-image: url(../images/site/common/body-bannar-bkground.png);
  /* background-color: add different color if needed */
}
```

Your JS:

```
 $('#id').removeClass('backgroundImage');
```

You only need to add or remove the backgroundImage class to your div if you want it to be displayed or not. Other background settings won't change.

Answer (score 1):

Just Try this :

```
$("div#id").css("background","");
$('div#id').css('backgroundColor', '#C1A3A5');
```

First Statement will remove background completely and second will attach only color to background